# Positive cable smoking......

Tags: electrical, gmc, sierra

I have a question. My truck has the battery next to the frame. Positive is almost impossible to get to. There is a positive red box in the engine to connect the positive jumper cable to. I had a dead truck. I called AAA. The guy that came out used the battery . When he removed the cables. He touched the frame. Twice. Causing smoke and sparks. Now I seem to be having issues with the switch on the door for my electric seat. I have a 04 GMC Sierra. It never gave me issues till now. Could the sparks n smoke from the cables cause this? I've asked around and ppl say yes. And some say no.

Comment: Unlikely, but test the switch. See what's missing and go from there.

Comment: "When he removed the cables. He touched the frame. Twice. Causing smoke and sparks."

That's really a beginners mistake that i wouldn't expect from an AAA guy. When you disconnect a battery you should *always* do the negative terminal first. Otherwise if you start working on the positive terminal and touch the car frame with your screwdriver you'll make a huge short with flying sparks (and probably a damaged screwdriver) as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Electrical issues are difficult to figure out without a lot of deadends. If you put YOUR seat in another truck and it worked fine, good.  If your door switches operate somebody else's perfectly working seat, good. If your seat's good and your switches are good, I'd check the relays and fuses - the truck's old enough that any of this could be age...the system is sensitive enough that the AAA guy could've accelerated your aging component's risk of failure: Test or have somebody test your relay's & get your seat exactly where you want it until then! Cheers!